# If $A\times B$ is countable, then $A$ is countable and $B$ is countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $A\times B$ is countable, then $A$ is countable and $B$ is countable?

The reverse is true but is there a counter example to above statement(except A or B empty set)? I couldn't find a mapping between $\mathbb N$ and $A\times B$ to prove this.

Comment: When you say countable, do you include finite sets?

Comment: yes any countable set including finite sets except empty set.

Comment: What? How does that make any sense? I get sometimes that finite sets are excluded and we have "finite, countable, and at most countable". But finite and non-empty is countable, but empty sets are not considered? That makes no sense to me. It feels like a really ad hoc definition.

Comment: Actually it is a step of the proof I make and I separately evaluated the case where A or B is empty thus it is excluded

Comment: I asked about the definition of countable. But okay, that makes more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A, B\neq \varnothing$, then $A\times B$ countable $\iff$ $A, B$ countable.

A proof of $\implies$ might make an injection $A\to A\times B$ by fixing a $b\in B$ (which is possible since $B\neq\varnothing$) and map any $a\in A$ to $(a, b)$, thus showing $|A|\leq |A\times B|$. Then do the same for $B\to A\times B$.

Comment: The OP wrote "except $A$ or $B$ empty set"

Comment: @RGS Not when I started writing this answer (I think...)

Comment: @Arthur No RGS is actually right. Anyway it doesn't matter you still answered the right question.

Comment: @Yanko I'm still not entirely convinced, and it's not something I can check (edits made to a question or an answer the first five minutes aren't logged). But yes, I removed that part and added a proof of the result the OP is asking about, so it doesn't really matter now.

Comment: I think it is useful to state the condition clearly in the answer anyway, because it is common for people to read the headline question and the answers without necessarily noting all the detail in the question. I think that makes this a better answer.

Comment: @MarkBennet I started the whole answer with "There is only one counterexample: When one of the sets is empty" So it was more blatant originally.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose neither $A$ nor $B$ are empty and suppose you have a mapping $h: \mathbb{N} \to A \times B$.

We can show that $|A| \leq |\mathbb{N}|$ by defining the function $f(a,b) = a$ and writing this *surjective* mapping:

$$f(h(n)): \mathbb{N} \to A$$.

To show $B$ is also countable, adapt $f$ to $f(a,b) = b$.

Answer (score 0):

If $A\times B$ is [countable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set) and $a_0\in A$ and $b_0\in B$ then there are **injective** functions $A\to A\times B$ and $B\to A\times B$ prescribed by $a\mapsto\langle a,b_0\rangle$ and $b\mapsto\langle a_0,b\rangle$ respectively.

Their existence implies that $A,B$ are both countable if $A\times B$ is countable. The first under extra condition that $B\neq\varnothing$ and the second under extra condition that $A\neq\varnothing$.

The injectivity ensures that the domain has the same cardinality as the image and in both cases the image is a subset of a countable set, hence is countable itself.